# Unable to play bluray movies or see bluray discs

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, blu-ray

I have a Optiarc BD ROM BC-5500S ATA Device and when I put bluray discs into the drive the computer doesn't read them. I hear the drive make 3 noises as if it's trying to read them. Nothing shows up in windows explorer. I am running windows 7 64bit. I can read DVDs and CDs just fine. Bluray seems to be the only problem.

I have installed PowerDVD9, HP DVD Play and HP DVD Media Smart and nothing helps. My laptop is a hp dv7 1273cl. I bought it before the free upgrades to windows 7 were available so I wasn't able to get the upgrade and so HP won't assist me beyond telling me to format and reinstall Vista.

Answer (score 1):

You've not mentioned installing the Optiarc drivers or firmware updates. That may be your best bet to start with:

http://www.sony-optiarc.eu/supportservice/downloads.html

Comment: According to the site and their customer support, since my drive came from HP I shouldn't use their firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the player you installed on your computer or the drive you use. Since the three you already tried don't work, how about give [Macgo Windows Blu-ray Player](http://download.cnet.com/Macgo-Windows-Blu-ray-Player/3000-13632_4-75453680.html?tag=mncol;9) ($39.95 with trial) a try.

If it still doesn't work, you should consider changing another Blu-ray drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with my acer aspire 8920G not playing blu-rays when I updated it from vista to 7. First thought was that the problem is in firmware, because when I tried play blu-ray it spinned 2-7 times and nothing happened. It didn't get recognized... I tried to solve this problem with different registration wipeouts etc.

Best solution was to first remove DVD/CD driver from device manager and then install newest powerDVD (trial-version works too) which have keys to unlock blu-ray-movies to you. Then restart computer and microsoft updates your DVD/CD driver to old 2006 version etc. (old version works!). Then I tried to play a movie and powerDVD recognized my blu-ray disk from 2014!

TL;DR:  1. REMOVE DVD/CD DRIVER 2.  INSTALL NEWEST POWERDVD 3. RESTART AND MICROSOFT UPDATES DVD/CD DRIVER 4. PROFIT

It's a shame I didn't look a solution earlier. I couldn't watch blu-ray movies for 5 years, but it's fixed now.

Sorry bad english.